# IntelliJ does not show Generate option

Tags: intellij-idea

In the keymap dialog, it show "^ + enter" will call up "Generate" dialog, but after I enter them, nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling groove plugin solved this problem, now the generate option shows.

[image: Enabling]

[image]

Refer:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001255380-IntelliJ-right-click-context-does-not-show-Generate-option-anymore-on-Windows-10